# How do you enable Big Head mode?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In *Batman: Arkham City*, there is apparently a secret big head mode. How is that mode enabled on each platform?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Kotaku](http://kotaku.com/5860674/how-to-activate-big+head-mode-in-batman-arkham-city) describes how to access this easter egg:

> It's very easy to do. You have to [have finished the game] on normal or hard, or on New Game+ (Which you can't unlock by completing the game on easy, anyway.) At any point in the game, take out Batman's Cryptographic Sequencer.  While holding down both RT and LT (or, I presume, R2 and L2 on PS3), begin to rotate your left thumbstick clockwise and your right thumbstick counter-clockwise. After doing that for a few seconds, you'll notice that the Dark Knight's chin has gotten a good deal…chinnier.

You can also watch the Rooster Teeth video (great channel for achievements and easter eggs, by they way!):

On the PC, it's a bit different.  You don't seem to need the cryptographic sequencer.  The [key combination](http://community.batmanarkhamcity.com/forums/showthread.php/11702-Does-pc-vison-have-big-head-mode-and-how-to-open-with-keyboard) is:

> U,U,U,D,D,D,L,L,R,L,L,U,U,D

or in WASD:

> W,W,W,S,S,S,A,A,D,A,A,W,W,S

And here's a video: